# Facebook Graph API get access token

Tags: php, json, facebook

I'm new to Facebook Development using PHP. I have created a nice script which gathers the facebook news feed from my fan page to a JSON array using the graph api.... 
eg//

```
  $url="https://graph.facebook.com/".$fbID."/feed?access_token=".$token."&limit=20";
```

(ghdn using the curl commands to collect the JSON..)

The problem is the access token expires after 2 hours, how can I make this not expire or renew?

Thanks for any help...

Comment: try the answer on this page.... [How do you renew an expired Facebook access token?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6711354/623952) or [another facebook/token answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9151853/623952)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it shows no prior research whatsoever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your fan page is public and has no restrictions like demographic restriction, then you can use your [App Access Token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/) to query and retrieve your fan page's feed.

In case your fan page is having restrictions you may use Page Access Token by giving your app `manage_pages` permission and retrieving Page Access Token using following Graph request

```
/{user-id}/accounts
```